# Does Python have ternary conditional with elif?

Tags: python, conditional-operator

I have recently found this question: [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator?rq=1) and discover something called ternary conditional `a = b if c == d else e`.

 My question: **There is a way to make ternary conditional with `elif`?** something like `a = b if c == d elif e == f i else j`.

Comment: You can nest ternary, yes, but why?

Comment: `'a' if 1 == 2 else 'b' if 2 == 3 else 'c'`

Comment: Sort of. You can nest ternary statements. But once you get to that point, I think that readability outweighs convenience and I'd just use a regular if statement.

Comment: As you wrote yourself, it is a ternary operator, having three operands. An `elif` would introduce two more.

Comment: @KlausD. Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chain the conditional operator, but it's not recommended, since it gets pretty hard to read. The associativity works the way you expect (like every language [aside from PHP](https://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/)):

```
a = b if c == d else i if e == f else j
```

which means in English "assign b to a if c equals d, otherwise, assign i if e equals f, and j if not."

Answer (score 3):

```
'Yes' if test1() else 'Maybe' if test2() else 'No'
```

<sub>PS. Also, be careful, you probably meant `a==b` which is checking for equality, rather than `a=b` which is assignment!</sub>

Comment: What is `test1()` and `test2()`?

Comment: any function or expression that returns a True or False value.

Comment: @EnderLook: They are just examples. You could replace them with your tests; e.g. `a == b` or `e == f`.

Comment: yes, as zondo said. In general, unless your test is very simple (like a==b), it's best to prefer appropriately named, readable functions to make your code read like English.

Comment: Also, it's important to realise the difference between the 'ternary operator' (i.e. `return_value1 if test1 else return_value2 if test2 else return_value3`) and a normal `if ... else` block, which _performs actions depending on the tests, but doesn't __return__ anything per se_.

Answer (score 2):

You can nest ternaries:

```
a = b if c == d else (i if e == f else j)
```

I can't think of any language that has a ternary operator with an `elseif` syntax. The name "ternary" means there are just 3 parts to the operator: condition, then, and else.